# I cannot type on the React text field

Tags: html, reactjs

I just can't type in the text fields. I am setting the state on constructor. Binding the functions as well. I can't find what is wrong.

This is my constructor...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email:'',
      password:''
    };
  }
```

This is the way I am handling the onChange...

```
handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState ({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
```

This is my from...

```
<form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input
                        type="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="exampleInputEmail1"
                        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                      ></input>
                      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
                        We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                      </small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                      <input
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.password}
                        type="password"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="exampleInputPassword1"
                        placeholder="Password"
                      ></input>
```

Comment: you don't have name attribute in input

Comment: You are setting the state through `name` attribute which is absent in your input tag. Please add name attribute as well . `<input  type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email"  value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} ></input>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to set the state correctly on change you need to have `name` attribute on input otherwise `e.target.name` won't be defined and the state won't be correctly set

```js
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
  <input
    type="email"
    name="email"
    class="form-control"
    id="exampleInputEmail1"
    aria-describedby="emailHelp"
    placeholder="Enter email"
    value={this.state.email}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  ></input>
  <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
    We'll never share your email with anyone else.
  </small>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
  <input
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    value={this.state.password}
    type="password"
    name="password"
    class="form-control"
    id="exampleInputPassword1"
    placeholder="Password"
  ></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a name attribute to the input fields

Answer (score 0):

you need to use defaultValue, value, onChange fields of the input field. Also use and useState hook to set value of control on value change

const [valueStr, setValueStr] = React.useState();

> <input type="text" defaultValue={item.name} value={valueStr}
> onChange={(e) => setValueStr(e.target.value)} />